# WooCommerce: Set country by default in checkout page for unlogged users

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, default, checkout

How to make the country default for regular (unregistered users). But if the buyer has a personal account and entered the country there, he would not be thrown into default in checkout?

I have tried to use [WooCommerce: Set country by default in checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104693/woocommerce-set-country-by-default-in-checkout-page/37104965#37104965) answer, but it does work for all users logged in and guest…

How to set the default country only for unregistered users?

Comment: Review: So, what did YOU try, and what was the result/error message? This might help answering the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `is_user_logged_in()` conditional tag as follows:

```
add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_country', 'change_default_checkout_country' );
add_filter( 'default_checkout_shipping_country', 'change_default_checkout_country' );
function change_default_checkout_country( $default ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $default = null;
    }
    return $default;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [WooCommerce: Set country by default in checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104693/woocommerce-set-country-by-default-in-checkout-page/37104965#37104965)

Comment: Thank you i add this code to snippet, and it work perfect)